# JSF 2.0 Application as Spring Web Bundle

Tags: spring, osgi, jsf-2

is it possible to run JSF **2.0** Application as Spring Web Bundle? Is there any OSGi support for JSF **2.0**? I didn't found any OSGified bundles for Apache MyFaces **2.0**.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

In case you're still interested. Yes it is possible. On the Virgo forums I know someone has got it running with the PrettyFaces lib e.g.

But you ask "Is there any OSGi support for JSF 2.0"...

the fact is (if I get it well... I'm still just learning OSGi) that you should look at it from the other point of view, meaning, is the JSF 2 stack structured/clean enough for being able to come nearer to the world of OSGI'ified zen. :)

Please keep this thread updated in case you find something useful. I'm putting a lot of time and effort in figuring this mess out and hope I'll be able to share a decent answer with you.

Best wishes,

Jochen

Answer (score 1):

10 month old thread, but posting this link if it helps someone:
'simple JSF 2 application on Virgo 3.0.0.RELEASE' -- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/203215/724346/#msg_724346

It's a great start for using JSF 2 in an OSGi envmt (Virgo Tomcat to be specific).
From there to making it work with Spring dm is a short hop.

1. add SpringBeanFacesELResolver to your faces-config.xml
2. add a WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml where you define your beans
3. in your web.xml add: (i) a contextClass param and set it to org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm.ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext, (ii) the Spring ContextLoaderListener
4. Create a META-INF/spring/osgi-context.xml where you declare/reference your Spring bean as an OSGi service:

   ```
   ...http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd" xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi">

       <osgi:reference id="springBeanId" interface="exposed.service.interface"/>
   ```

HTH someone.